# Problem to see Live Preview Cannot find a View struct in scope SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui

When I want to load or call a view into another view, I have an error, but I can run simulator and see the app works fine; it just doesn't let me see Live Preview in Xcode.

#### The error I have:

```
Cannot find 'HomeTemplate' in scope
```

#### Sample code:

```swift
struct HomeController: View {
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            HomeTemplate()
        }
    }
}

struct HomeController_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        HomeController()
    }
}
```

#### And `HomeTemplate` file:

```swift
import SwiftUI
struct HomeTemplate: View {
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
            VStack {
                Text("Your Daily")
                    .font(.system(size: 25, weight: .bold))
                    .foregroundColor(Color.secondary)
                    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
                
                Text("Recommendation")
                    .font(.system(size: 25, weight: .bold))
                    .foregroundColor(Color.primary)
                    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
            }
            .padding(.horizontal, 22)
            .padding(.top, 30)
            
            ScrollViewListSlideStyleOne()
        }
    }
}

struct HomeTemplateView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        HomeTemplate()
    }
}
```

Why doesn't it let me call a struct or class wherever I want? I saw the other similar questions, but they just import SwiftUI, and it works for them, but I added it before.

By the way, I uploaded my project on GitHub and you can access to it:

https://github.com/shahryarjb/MishkaCmsiOS

[image: SwiftUI scope problem]

Comment: Cloned your repo and everything builds as expected, using Xcode 13.2; did you try to clean project and delete derived data?

Comment: @RicoCrescenzio I pushed Product → Clean Build folder and re-build it, but still does not work, I am using Xcode 13.1, you think Xcode has this bug?

Comment: is `struct HomeTemplateView_Previews` right? Shouldn't it be  `struct HomeTemplate_Previews `

Comment: @shahryartavakkoli Remove your `HomeController` from the Membership Target MishkaCmsiOSUITests. That should fix the problem.

Comment: I'd try to remove as membership target as @Anwuna said, or even delete file and re-add to project. Try to delete Derived data, I think this is a Xcode bug.

Comment: @shahryartavakkoli I'm able to live priview the `HomeController` doing what I suggested. Verify that you did the following: 
1. Go to File inspector 
2. Under Target Membership
3. Uncheck `HomeController` from `MishkaCmsiOSUITests` target.

Comment: @Anwuna Thank you, you are right I deleted the target which is for UItest and it worked

Comment: @Anwuna Thank you, you are right I deleted the target which is for UItest and it worked